# Send publications between two Raspberry Pis in different countries

Tags: networking, communication, mqtt

I am looking to start a project where I can establish a communication between two RPis worldwide, basically to have a small distance relationship gadget (e.g. When i press a button on my RPi, the other RPi receives a signal and emits a sound).
I am completely new to the world of online communication, and I know very little about comm protocols and so on, therefore I do not even know what to search online to help me.

I have seen than a public online MQTT server would do the trick, but 1st I am unsure about this and 2nd I don't know if it's a viable option (secure, free, etc.). I have no idea if there is any other way to do such things.
Also, another issue that I might encounter is that my relative lives in China and I am not sure if it can work fine, since their internet have a specific firewall.

Do you have any hint on where I can start to look at, or what keywords I should search for ?
Maybe this is just completely undoable at my scale, please let me know if that's the case.

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: See [Tour](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) to see how this site works
and [How do I ask a good question?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: the `different countries` is irrelevant ... it would be the same between your house and your neighbor's house, unless one of the countries blocks internet traffic, but that's a different problem

Comment: The Fire Wall is very hot - don't touch it.

Comment: `completely undoable at my scale` what? one computer talking to one other computer? that's not even ON any scale :p

Comment: @jsotola right, I should have been more specific then, I am indeed talking about a country that blocks internet traffic.

Comment: @JaromandaX I meant that it was maybe not something easy to do for an individual like me :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick update, I found that using a free online MQTT broker was the best option for me.
Using the paho-mqtt library for python with HiveMQ broker worked just fine.